# TextView: display text in preview only, not during runtime

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, textview

Is there a way to have text displayed in the preview pane in Android studio but not in the actual app while running on the phone?

I currently use the `android:hint` attribute, which is quite useful to see how much space a `TextView` requires or what size the text will be.

The problem, however, is that in case no text is assigned to the `TextView`, the hint shows in the app.

Is there a way to have the text display only in android studio but not at runtime?

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. But I did search SO first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's `tools:text="some text"`. This only will be visible in Android Studio.

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#design-time_view_attributes):

> You can insert sample data in your layout preview by using the **tools:** prefix instead of **android:** with any  attribute from the Android framework. This is useful when the attribute's value isn't populated until runtime but you want to see the effect beforehand, in the layout preview.
>
> For example, if the **android:text** attribute value is set at runtime or you want to see the layout with a value different than the default, you can add **tools:text** to specify some text for the layout preview only.

[image]